# jQuery validation plugin checks inputs between different rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validation plugin to check values from two dynamically generated rows. But I am confused by the jquery selection. Below is my broken [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/godhong/fdmN3/) and I appreciate all inputs.

My HTML table is something like

```
<tr class="tab_noa1"><td><input name="jm' + i + '" type="text" size="5" value="' + i + '"/></td><td><input type="text" size="5" name="mm' + i + '" id="id_mm' + i + '"/></td></tr>
```

which is generated based on user selection. Then I need to start from elements named `mmi` (the ith row), and find

a. its previous row's value `mmi-1` (it did not work)

```
 $(element).parent().prev('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').children('input').val();
```

b. its left neighbor in the same row `jm_i-1`

```
$(element).parent().prev('td').children('input').val();
```

### Found out that I missed `.parent()` in selection a. It should be

```
$(element).parent().parent().prev('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').children('input').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to do this when the submit button is clicked?  If that's the case you can put a class on both the `app` and `month` inputs so they are easier to grab with jQuery. In the submit handler you can grab all the rows and iterate over them backwards and interrogate the `app` input value and previous row's `month` value.  Here's an updated fiddle that prints the values you mentioned to the console: http://jsfiddle.net/fdmN3/2/

Comment: Yes. Add a class would be a shortcut! Thanks!

Comment: @tao.hong if this solves your issue, please accept as answer.